# Wordpress post API with the request's body

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm trying to make a POST request to klaviyo using their API by `wp_remote_post()`.
This is their guide:

URL:
POST [https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/{LIST_ID}/members](https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/%7BLIST_ID%7D/members)

Example Request:

```
{
    "api_key": "api_key_comes_here",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "email": "george.washington@example.com",
            "example_property": "valueA"
        },
        {
            "email": "thomas.jefferson@example.com",
            "phone_number": "+12223334444",
            "example_property": "valueB"
        }
    ]
}
```

api_key:    stringThe API key for your account.

profiles:   list of JSON objectsThe profiles that you would like to add to the list. Each object in the list must have an email, phone_number, or push_token key. You can also provide additional properties as key-value pairs.

This is what i tried:

```
    $profiles = ['email' => $content];
    $args = ["api_key" => {API_key},
             "profiles" => json_encode($profiles)
        ];
    
 $res = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_post( 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/{LIST_ID}/members', [
        'body'=> $args
    ] ));
```

and the response is: "unable to parse profiles"

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i find the solution for this:

> #1: add  'content type' => application/json to headers

> #2: force the profile array into object - due to the guild said: profiles parameter is list of JSON objects

Working codes:

```
$args = ["api_key" => "your_API_key",
         "profiles" => array(
                (object)['email' => 'email@something.success']
             )
        ];



    $res = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_post( 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/you_list_ID/members', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => json_encode($args)
    ]));
```

Thank **@j4g0** for all of your help.
Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

You are not encoding your complete request body like the example request seems to suggest

```
$args = [
    "api_key" => 'some_api_key_string',
    "profiles" => [
        [
            "email" => "john_doe@somewhere.com",
            "value" => "some value",
        ],
        [
            "email" => "jane_doe@somewhere.com",
            "value" => "some other value",
        ]
    ],
];


$listId = 123;

$url = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/{$listId}/members";

$response = wp_remote_post($url, json_encode($args));
```

this will give you an output like in the example

Comment: thank for your time and answer. When i use: json_encode($args). This's response i get: "The API key specified is invalid". I think - that mean the first solution is ok except the profiles encode (sever recognize the API_key and profiles parameter but can't parse) but the second - neither of them are recognized!

Comment: did you replace the api_key in my example with yours? also if your original post contains your actual api_key you should remove it since that is something you do not want to make public

Comment: also how are you making sure to input the LIST_ID in 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/{LIST_ID}/members' ? I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your time and patient. Yes, the API key and the LIS_ID is show in my Klaviyo accout setting page. And i had used these two infos to make get request and it's work!

Comment: if your question has been answered would you be so kind as to mark it as such by approving my answer or create your own answer with how you achieved it and approve that?

Comment: sorry if i make you missunderstand. My problem is still there. I mean - i had already change my real API key and List ID to your codes and i still get this response: "The API key specified is invalid". Althought i has using these to make test Get request and it work!

Comment: 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/{LIST_ID}/members' this does not seem to be formed correctly though, since you are using ' which will keep the literal {LIST_ID} string instead of replacing it. Plus in order to replace it you would need to mark it like {$LIST_ID}

Comment: i had even hard code the url: $url = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/my_list_ID/members"; and it's still not working!

Comment: sorry, i fail to see what we are doing differently from the example. Did you try postman or insomnia to make request to this route to see if it is available or contact the ones responsible for the API. I can not find a documentation on klaviyo.com at least not without creating an account

Comment: you might want to set the headers like in this example Maybe you could set the header like so https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/#div-comment-3495

Comment: Anyway, thank so much for your effort! I think it's because the way the wp_remote_post() parse the qurey request. I had tried and always success with other request - wich using single dimention aray or just string parameter. For other - which use multidimention array always fails!